# Binding to a Property and also to one of its Properties

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a `Path` shape, which I want to bind to a `StreamGeometry`. This `StreamGeometry` also have a `Transform` property that should be bound.

My viewmodel has `Scale` property of type `Transform`, and `DatGeometry` of type `StreamGeometry`.

Now I can't figure how to bind to these properties. Here's what I got:

```
    <Path>
        <Path.Data>             
            <GeometryGroup Transform="{Binding Scale}">
                <!-- Want to bind to "DatGeometry" here, or something equivalent
                     (if possible without resorting to GeometryGroup -->
            </GeometryGroup>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```

Another approach could be:

```
    <Path Data="{Binding DatGeometry}">
        <!-- But how should I assess "DatGeometry.Transform" now,
             so that I could bind "Scale" to it? -->
    </Path>
```

Comment: Why can't you just create DatGeometry with Scale assigned. They come from the same view model don't they?

Comment: You can even create a Binding to Transform property in view model.

Comment: @GregorStamač tell me a thing: if DatGeometry comes with Scale assigned, then if I change Scale, would the rendered whatever from DatGeometry also update? My idea is that I can somewhat "independently" update only the transform (since the geometry itself is not expected to change).

Comment: @GregorStamač as for your second comment, that is my current situation: ViewModel has two independent properties: StreamGeometry and Transform. What I would like is to bind StreamGometry's Transform, IN XAML, to the Transform property in ViewModel (well, at least it was my first idea).

Comment: It's not possible to do that since view model is providing StreamGeometry. You want to provide a binding to a property of something you don't have.

Comment: @GregorStamač I believe this last statement has the definitive point. I am already considering to have some object with multibinding, so that I can combine Geometry, Transform, etc. when property changes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this

```
<Path Data="{Binding DatGeometry}">
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Scale}" ScaleY="{Binding Scale}"/>
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
```

Comment: `Path.LayoutTransform` is probably a better choice, but otherwise, I'd go with this.

Comment: Well, that has the very effect I am trying to avoid: this distorts the path thickness. By transforming the geometry-before-the-rendering instead of the rendered output, I hope to have constant, scale-independent path thickness. By the way, if this was not an issue, it works very well (already used this approach in another application).

Comment: (also, note that I am more curious about the binding issues than the graphics/drawing/rendering issues here. The types involved, and the task at hand, are incidental in the context of the question)